# Unit Testing Spring WebClient Api call

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, spring-boot-test, spring-webclient

I am using Spring Web module for writing REST Apis and using WebClient class to call external apis and using block() method to wait for the response.

I understand that I should write REST apis in fully non blocking way using Spring WebFlux. But that is not an option here.

I am having trouble writing unit tests and Mocking WebClient. I have read few WebClient mocking threads in Stack Overflow but none of them seems to be working in my case.

Following is my code

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = null;
        
        try {
            response = webClient
                    .post()
                    .uri(uriBuilder())
                    .bodyValue(request)
                    .retrieve()
                    .toEntity(String.class)
                    .block();
           } catch (WebClientResponseException e) {
 
            // Process different types of exceptions here

           if (e.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) {
           // process HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND exception here
           }

         }
```

Can anyone please let me know how to unit test of this code?

Request class is a POJO class. uriBuilded() method returns an uri.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking WebClient could be very tricky and error-prone. Even if you could cover some simple positive cases, it would be very hard to test more complex scenarios, like error handling, retries, ...

I would recommend [WireMock](https://wiremock.org/) which provides a very good API for testing web clients. Here are some examples

```
stubFor(get("/api")
        .willReturn(aResponse()
                .withHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .withStatus(200)
                .withBody(...)
        )
);
```

You could easily test both positive and negative scenarios by providing different stubs

```
stubFor(get("/api")
        .willReturn(aResponse()
                .withHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .withStatus(500)
        )
);
```

or test retry logic using [Scenarios](https://wiremock.org/docs/stateful-behaviour/) or even simulate timeouts using [Delays](https://wiremock.org/docs/simulating-faults/).

In addition, I would suggest to avoid `try-catch` on this level, handle errors using reactive operators & web client API like `.onStatus` or `.onErrorResume`, return `Mono` and block on a higher level.